# How to create a table that stores data from a view - MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

MySQL database (5.5)

I have created a view that produces one row of data every time it is refreshed:

## curtime(), span, curSPM

15:19:38, 5, 454.2000

two objectives here:

1. - have this view refreshed every 4 minutes -
2. Store data from that view into a permanent table that collects the records (to be able to view historical data).

Basically,  I'm trying to capture and STORE "live" data. I've tried creating a procedure to run the query - and I can create the table - but I can not get the table to store the data. Any ideas on what step(s) I might be missing?

UPDATED Question:

HERE is my procedure (or the procedure I'm working on) -

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pullSPMM2
BEGIN () 
Insert INTO testTable (SELECT * FROM Machine2SPM);
END //
DELIMITER;
```

A few things - I know it's not completely correct yet - (this isn't my original - I started over as a clean slate).

I'm not sure what parameter I need to put first of all

Secondly, once I have the procedure that inserts the latest row into the table -
I know I need to schedule an event to run every 5 minutes. Something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
    DO
      #procedure to insert row into table;
```

Comment: Please include your stored procedure if you want it reviewed.

Comment: I apologize - will get it up shortly. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr - does this give better information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a different way to do it that's a little more effective (and simpler). I was over complicating it (so easy to do, sometimes).

```
CREATE EVENT CollectM2SPM ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 Minute ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO Insert INTO testTable (SELECT * FROM M2SPM);
```

I also need to run this to get it started: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Hope someone else find this helpful as well! :)

Thanks!